# Adding application to Default Website in Windows 10

Tags: iis

In Windows 10 I tried to add an application to the Default Web Site via command line.  In the IIS gui, if I right click on Default Web site and add application I can enter the alias, and physical path.  I'd like to do the same via command line but I've had no success.

My attempts have been around appcmd but can't seem to get the structure right.

For example:
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add app -site.name "Default Web Site/test"

All the searches seem to point to older versions of IIS.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What keywords did you use to perform searches? A typical search engine should return lots of posts on appcmd itself, and the top result from Microsoft contains tons of examples, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#creating-sites-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools

Answer (score 1):

This format is usually used in this command: `/attribute:value` ,something like this:

```
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/test /physicalPath:C:\The\Path\To\Your\App
```